# Java 8 stream grouping by on property ignoring case sensitive

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following classes:

LivingPlace:

```
public class LivingPlace {
    public LivingPlace(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    private String province;

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }
}
```

User:

```
public class User {
    private LivingPlace viv;
    private int age;

    public User(LivingPlace viv, int age) {
        this.viv = viv;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public LivingPlace getLivingPlace() {
        return viv;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

And then on my Main class I have a list of Users.
I want to get the amount of users below the age of 18, grouped by province (knowing that the name of provinces of each user can have any combination of upcase or lowercase letters).
I thought something like:

```
    Map<String, Integer> rta = users.stream()
            .filter(user -> user.getAge() < 18 && user.getLivingPlace() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince(), Collectors.counting()));
```

However this won't compile.

Any ideas?

I get several errors:

```
* method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> us) -> {}, Collector<Object,?,Long>)
* The method getLivingPlace() is undefined for the type T
* method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> us) -> {}, Collector<Object,?,Long>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grouping operations you should use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) because [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) will take `Function` as arguments

```
Map<String, Long> rta = users.stream().filter(user -> user.getAge() < 18 && user.getLivingPlace() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince(), Collectors.counting()));
```

As @Holger suggested you can also use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with merge function when you expect a large number of groups with small counts

```
Map<String, Integer> rta = users.stream()
.filter(user -> user.getAge() < 18 && user.getLivingPlace() != null)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince(), 
    a -> 1L, Integer::sum));
```

And if you want to perform grouping operation by ignoring cases, you can either convert `province` to lower case or upper case

```
Map<String, Long> rta = users.stream().filter(user -> user.getAge() < 18 && user.getLivingPlace() != null)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince().toLowerCase(), Collectors.counting()));
```

or you can use `TreeMap` with `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator

```
Map<String, Long> result = users.stream()
      .filter(user -> user.getAge() < 18 && user.getLivingPlace() != null)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince(),
            () -> new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: You can also use `toMap`, like `Collectors.toMap(us -> us.getLivingPlace().getProvince(), us -> 1L, Integer::sum)`. Since this bears boxing overhead, it will be less efficient when you have less groups but large counts, whereas the `toMap` approach can be more efficient when you expect a large number of groups with small counts. In fact, they screwed it up in Java 8. In Java 8, `counting()` is always less efficient, but this has been fixed in Java 9.

Comment: Thank you so much @Holger for such a good information, but if you don't mind may i know where did you gain this knowledge `they screwed it up in Java 8. In Java 8, counting() is always less efficient, but this has been fixed in Java 9` by developing this or is there any documentation that you can suggest ?

Comment: @Deadpool I got pointed at it long time ago in some Q&A here on Stackoverflow, then a look into the source code revealed that it had been implemented as `reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum)` which bears the same boxing overhead as the `toMap` approach but requires a finisher which runs over the entire map at the end, due to the way, the `reducing` collector works. The best permanent pointer to the issue is [JDK-8136686](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136686) which shows that it has been fixed for Java 9 by working like `summingLong(e -> 1L)` without boxing overhead.